# JQuery: disable button on certain select option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have form with dropdown list of collections. After selecting and submitting one of the collections I want to disable button. So that user cannot submit that collection option again. Ajax works well, and the button is disabled on success. However, after I scroll dropdown list, the button becomes enabled again.

**Form**

```
<form id="addToCollection">
<select id="collection_bundle_add_to_collection">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose a collection</option>
    <option value="{{ id }}">{{ name }}</option>
</select>

<input  id="add-object-to-collection"
    type="submit" value="Add" class="button"/>
```

**Submit Ajax**

```
 $('#addToCollection').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#add-object-to-collection").val('Adding...');
    var url = '{{ path('collection_submit_object', {'id': '{{ id }}'}) }}';
    var data = $('#addToCollection').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type : 'POST',
        data: data
    }).done(function( data ) {
        if (data.error){
            $('#addErrorMessage').css("display","inline");
        }
        else{
            $("#add-object-to-collection").val('Added');
            $("#add-object-to-collection").prop('disabled', true);
            $('#addErrorMessage').css("display","none");
        }
    });
});
```

**Change Javascript** checks if select option value is in col_exists array. col_exists is an array of submitted collections, *if* checks if the value of option is in this array. If yes, the button is disabled

```
  $("#collection_bundle_add_to_collection").change(function() {
      if (col_exists.indexOf($("#collection_bundle_add_to_collection").val()) >= 0) {
                $("#add-object-to-collection").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#add-object-to-collection").attr('value', 'Added');
                }
                else {
                $("#add-object-to-collection").prop('disabled', false);
                $("#add-object-to-collection").attr('value', 'Add');
                }
        });
```

In gif below you can see that I selected and submitted col1 first, and button has become disabled. When I selected col3 and went back to col1,the button for col1 is enabled again. This can make user to submit col1 again.

[image]

Comment: What is the component being used for drop-down list? Can you please create a plunkr that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @GaneshKumar added gif showing live demonstration, hope it's explains the problem

Comment: The component for dropdown is select.

Comment: There is some javascript attached to the selects onchange event. Please show that

Comment: @Steve I added JavaScript attached to select

Comment: Ok well the else section of that code clearly removes the disabled attribute - thats whats causing the behavior. I dont know what that code is supposed to do, so maybe you can just remove the else section, maybe not. - what is the `col_exists` variable?

Comment: @Steve col_exists is an array of submitted collections, if checks if the value of option is in this array. If yes, the button is disabled

Comment: Yes, and if its not in the array, it enables the button. Thats exactly what its doing. If you dont want that behaviour, then remove the else clause. I dont  really understand your problem here.

Comment: Oh, is the problem that it stays enabled when you try and select `col1` for the second time? Please show the code where you create the `col_exists` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You dont appear to add the submited value to your `col_exists` array at any point, so the function attached to the selects change event always runs the else code branch, enabling the button.

To fix add the value to the array:

```
$('#addToCollection').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#add-object-to-collection").val('Adding...');
    var url = '{{ path('collection_submit_object', {'id': '{{ id }}'}) }}';
    var data = $('#addToCollection').serialize();
    var columnSelected = $("#collection_bundle_add_to_collection").val(); //get value
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type : 'POST',
        data: data
    }).done(function( data ) {
        if (data.error){
            $('#addErrorMessage').css("display","inline");
        }
        else{
            col_exists.push(columnSelected); //add to array
            $("#add-object-to-collection").val('Added');
            $("#add-object-to-collection").prop('disabled', true);
            $('#addErrorMessage').css("display","none");
        }
    });
});
```

This presumes that `col_exists` is an array, and is accessible in a parent scope

Comment: col_exists was declared in another file, but thanks for help anyway. You showed what was wrong with my initial code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking in the mysterious `col_exists` array, why not, on ajax success, simply disable the appropriate option.

```
$('#addToCollection').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $selectedOption = $("#collection_bundle_add_to_collection", this).find(':selected'); // <<< Remember the selected option at the moment the form is submitted.

    $("#add-object-to-collection").val('Adding...').prop('disabled', true);// <<< disable here to prevent another click while adding is in progress

    var url = '{{ path('collection_submit_object', {'id': '{{ id }}'}) }}';
    var data = $(this).serialize();// you can use $(this) here
    $.ajax({
        'url': url,
        'type': 'POST',
        'data': data
    }).done(function(data) {
        if (data.error) {
            $('#addErrorMessage').css('display', 'inline');
        } else {
            $selectedOption.prop('disabled', true);//<<< make sure the option cannot be reselected.
            $('#add-object-to-collection').val('Added');//<<< already disabled above, so no need to disable again
            $('#addErrorMessage').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
});
```

Then, there's no need to test anything in the select menu's 'change' handler, though you still need to re-eneable the "add" button.

```
$("#collection_bundle_add_to_collection").change(function() {
    $("#add-object-to-collection").val('Add').prop('disabled', false);
});
```